# UTF 16 code for apostrophe showing as a question mark

Tags: jsp, special-characters, utf-16

In my jsp file that is deployed inside a portal server,  Ineed to display a special character (apostrophe). This character will be read from a properties file. So I dig up the UTF-16 code for apostrophe. It is \u2019. On my local machine it works fine. But on the SIT machine, it shows up as a '?' (question mark).

Where can I begin my investiation? I have tried the apostrophe itself also (') in my proeprties file. It shows up both in my local and SIT as /'. i..e there is a slash in the front.

Comment: Maybe a problem with Little vs Big Endian …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question mark means either

1. the properties file is UTF-16 encoded and being displayed as-is, but the font being used to display that UTF-16 text does not support Unicode codepoint U+2019.
2. the properties file is decoded to a charset that does not support Unicode codepoint U+2019 before the decoded data is then being displayed.